# Feeds import and related fields

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds, importing-exporting

I have a content type with an entity reference field (I suppose a term reference field would work as well).  The target type is a taxonomy term.  The taxonomy term has a name and ID field (among others).  My feeds source that I would like to import has the taxonomy ids that I can import but I'd like to display the name not the id.  My problem is I can't get the feeds map correctly unless I have a list of names in my feeds source, not ids.

Thanks
Sharon

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.  If I import the ID field as GUID when adding the taxomony terms, then I can select that as an option when I import into my content type :)